# Docker postgres "psql: FATAL: role "root" does not exist"

Tags: fedora, docker, postgresql

I started a postgres docker container using

`sudo docker run --name some-postgres -d postgres`

and then attempted to connect to it using

`sudo docker run -it --rm --link some-postgres:postgres postgres psql -h postgres`

which gives the error `psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`

These commands are exactly the same as the ones listed on the [docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) Only run as root and without `-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword`

Have I done something wrong here? What could be causing this?

Answer (score 11):

```
$ docker run --rm --name some-postgres -d postgres
cb2ddbb0f4f715077ebc1bfc2dc7151e5a6d07cd374c28be1db6d6ad77b9b16a

$ docker run -it --rm --link some-postgres:postgres postgres psql -h postgres -U postgres
psql (10.4 (Debian 10.4-2.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

You forgot the `-U postgres`